# Proving that any finite set of real numbers is bounded

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The definition given is that (this is a discrete course)
$S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is bounded if 
$$\exists M,N \in \mathbb{R} : M < s<N \qquad \forall s\in S.$$

This is what I tried:
Suppose $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with $A = \{a_1,a_2 , \ldots,a_n\}$ and suppose, WLOG, that $a_1 \leq a_2 \leq a_3 \leq \ldots \leq a_n$.

Then pick $M:= a_1 - 1$ and $N = a_n + 1$ so
$$M < a < N \qquad \forall a \in A.$$

I'm not sure if this is valid. I feel like I'm just assuming that $a_n + 1$ exists or something..

Comment: Yes, your choice $M$ and $N$ is valid.

Comment: Another way would be to pick $N=|a_0|+\cdots+|a_n|$ and $M=-N$.

Comment: It kind of depends on what tools you have access to.  I feel like the WLOG is not really justified, as it implicitly assumes that you can order a finite set, which requires the ability to pick out the least element, which assumes *a priori* that there is a lower bound.  I would be more comfortable with an induction proof.

Comment: @ copper.hat: Very nice, but I think you should add 1 to the sum to take care of the cases where all the values or all the values but one are zero. Also, I think that you should make that an answer instead of just a comment, since that is what it is.

Answer (score 2):

A proof by induction (we are only going to go for the lower bound, but the upper bound is similar):

As a base case, note that a singleton set $\{a_1\}$ (with $a_1\in \mathbb{R}$) is bounded by $M = a_1 - \varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon > 0$.  Note also that we can bound sets $\{a_1, a_2\}$ with two elements:  by trichotomy, either $a_1 < a_2$, $a_2 < a_1$, or the two are equal.  In the first case set $M = a_1 - \varepsilon$, in the second case set $M = a_2 - \varepsilon$.  These are equivalent in the third case.  (We could skip this step by using total induction, but I've already typed it out, so what are you gonna do?)

For induction, suppose that for any set of real numbers with $n$ elements, we can find upper and lower bounds, and suppose that $\{a_1,\dotsc,a_{n+1}\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is some finite set.  By the induction hypothesis, we may choose $M_1$ such that $M_1 < a_j$ for all $j \in \{1,\dotsc,n\}$, and $M_2$ such that $M_2 < a_j$ for all $\{2,\dotsc,n+1\}$.  By the argument above, we may find $M$ such that $M < M_1$ and $M < M_2$, from which it follows by the transitivity of the "less than" relation that $M < a_j$ for all $j\in\{1,\dotsc,n+1\}$ and completes the induction argument.

---

This may be overkill, but I find it more convincing than the statement "without loss of generality," which I find a little bit suspect in this case.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more elegant answer, provided in the comments three years ago by copper.hat:

Let $A = \{a_1, a_2, \dotsc, a_n\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a finite set.  Define
$$ M = \sum_{k=1}^{n} |a_n|. $$
Then $M$ is an upper bound of $A$:  if $x \in A$, then there is some $j \in \{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$ such that $x = a_j$.  Hence
$$ x = a_j \le |a_j| \le |a_j| + \sum_{\substack{k=1\\ k\ne j}}^{n} |a_k| = M.$$
By a similar argument, $-M \le x$ for each $x\in A$.  Then, as strict inequalities are required in the definition given in the original question $-(M+1) < x < M+1$ for every $x \in A$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a finite set of real numbers, say

$$\{ a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots, a_{n} \}.$$

Since the set is finite, WOLG we may assume that the $a_{i}$ have been arranged in non-decreasing order.

Let $M = a_{1} - 1$ and $N = a_{n} + 1$.

Then  $\forall x \in X,$ it follows that

$$ M < x < N.$$

Therefore, $X$ is bounded.